# How to list all subdocuments of a mongodb document in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, datagridview

I like to show all embedded subdocuments of a mongodb document in a datagridview in C#. Should not be so difficult I thought but so far could not find any similar question and useful answer. 
I use the docs.mongodb.com example below:

```
{   
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

Unfortunately it does not work to find the document and then step through the array of subdocuments like:

```
var doc = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", "joe");
foreach (var a in doc.addresses)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = a["street"].ToString();
   ...
}
```

Trying to include the subdocuments only does not bring me to the subdocument level either:

```
var result = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument("_id", "joe")).Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("addresses").Exclude("_id")).ToListAsync();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Datagridview is a table-row-column structure based grid. you will have to  find a way to flatten your document structure into rows & columns.

Comment: It is not so much the datagridview that puzzles me but the foreach statement. I do not know how to step through the embedded array elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the result should be treated as nested arrays.
So looping through the elements was able with:

```
    while (result[0]["addresses"][i]["_id"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtprops.NewRow();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            try { dr[col.DataPropertyName] = result[0]["addresses"][i][col.DataPropertyName]; }
            catch { };
        }
        dtprops.Rows.Add(dr);
        i++;
    };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtprops;
```

I do not like the try catch part but have not found out yet how to avoid document fields that do not exist. But that is a different issue.